# How to exit from the camera view?

Tags: python, 3d-view, camera

With this code fragment, I can enter the camera view correctly, but I'd like to be able to get out.

```
 for a in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
        if a.type == 'VIEW_3D': 
            for r in a.regions: 
                if r.type == 'WINDOW': 
                    override = {'window': bpy.context.window,
                                'area': a, 
                                'region': r,
                                'scene': bpy.context.scene,
                                'active_object': camera}
                    bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera(override)
```

Comment: uh, is it important that you use python to exit?  this can be done easily with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Millard it is not very important, but it is necessary to understand

Comment: I was just making sure you wanted a python answer.  I'm not sure how to do this in python, was just making sure you knew it could be done with a shortcut.  lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`view3d.viewnumpad`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=viewnumpad#bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad) operation.
Pass on the `override` context, just like in your example code. This snippet can also be used to enter the active camera's view.

```
bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(override, type='CAMERA')
```